# mergeStyles can't child (by id) of parent (by class)

Tags: css, fluent-ui, css-in-js, fluentui-react

For something like the following:

```
<div class="example">
  <div id="label">
    Label text
  </div>
</div>
```

The following CSS is able to style 'Label text'

```
.example #label {
  color: red;
}
```

But it does not work with fluentUI mergeStyles:

```
const RedLabelStyles = mergeStyles({
  ".example #label": {
    color: "red"
  }
});
```

I know it's a problem with the selector, not the CSS itself, because the following correctly applies styles:

```
const RedLabelStyles = mergeStyles({
  "#label": {
    color: "red"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was due to the `RedLabelStyles` selector being applied to the `<div class="example">` itself. It works as expected if the JSX is as follows:

```
<div class={RedLabelStyles}>
  <div class="example">
    <div id="label">
      Label text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```